# Нужна ли запятая перед несогласованным определением после указательного местоимения?

Tags: пунктуация

Рынок арматуры за 2 года адаптировался к уровню низких цен на азиатскую арматуру и стал не готов покупать эту же (,) среднего качества арматуру по более высоким ценам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рынок арматуры за 2 года адаптировался к уровню низких цен на азиатскую арматуру и стал не готов покупать эту же, среднего качества, арматуру по более высоким ценам.

Определение лучше обособить как уточняющее.

Похожий пример: "Я увидел на белой шапке кургана рдяно-жёлтую, с огнистым отливом, лису".

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Я бы немного отредактировал фразу, чтобы она меньше напоминала машинный перевод: "Рынок за два года адаптировался к низкому уровню цен на азиатскую арматуру и не готов покупать эту же, среднего качества, арматуру по более высоким ценам"